# Replacing 'GetTimeZoneTypeEnum' class with kentico 9 API

Tags: c#, calendar, kentico

I upgraded my kentico project from 8.2 to 9.
In version 9 'GetTimeZoneTypeEnum' class is removed but in my project it is used at some places. How Can I replace that with version 9 API.
I referred kentico 9 API, they said to use 'EnumStringRepresentationExtensions' class. I tried to work with that but that isn't working.

My code snippet is:

```
if (GetValue("timezonetype") != null)            
{
  timePicker.TimeZone = TimeZoneInfoProvider.**GetTimeZoneTypeEnum**(ValidationHelper.GetString(GetValue("timezonetype"), ""));
}
```

Getting error at **GetTimeZoneTypeEnum**. Can anyone give some more details to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace this function and use the EnumStrinRepresentaionExtensions.

To get the enum value from the property timezonetype

```
if (GetValue("timezonetype") != null)
{
       timePicker.TimeZone = EnumStringRepresentationExtensions.ToEnum<CMS.Globalization.TimeZoneTypeEnum>(ValidationHelper.GetString(GetValue("timezonetype"), ""));
}
```

to set the property:

```
SetValue("timezonetype",EnumStringRepresentationExtensions.ToStringRepresentation<CMS.Globalization.TimeZoneTypeEnum>(value))
```

value should be of type CMS.Globalization.TimeZoneTypeEnum

Comment: Thanks..Solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

The method was removed. You need to use the TimeZoneTypeEnum itself:

```
Inherit  0   Indicates whether time zone type is inherited.  
Server   1   Server timezone type.  
WebSite  2   WebSite timezone type.  
User     3   User timezone type.  
Custom   4   Custom timezone type.
```

If you have those time zones in some string format please convert them to the enum above or you indexes (switch-case, second column).